# Format date string to required format using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, react-native

I have the below date which I need to convert to `'dd/MM/yyyy'` and `'HH:mm'`. How can I achieve this without using `getHours()` or `moment.js` (Most of the answers are using either of these)?

`2017-11-24T16:05:00Z`

Comment: Just reformat the string, no need to create a Date. But there are many questions already on [*parsing ISO format strings*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+how+to+parse+ISO+format+string) and then [*formatting a date*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript).

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for customization then below code will help you

```
var dt='2017-11-24T16:05:00Z'
dtArray=dt.split('T')
dateArray=dtArray[0].split('-') //dtArray[0] manupulating date
result = dateArray.reverse().join('/')
console.log(result) //"24/11/2017"
```

similar way you do for HH:MM

```
time=dtArray[1].split(':').slice(0,2).join(':')
```

Comment: All those array methods… consider `var b = dt.split(/\D/); result = b[2]+'/'+b[1]+'/'+b[0]`. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex groups :

```
var myDate = "2017-11-24T16:05:00Z";
var myRegexp = /(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/
var match = myRegexp.exec(myDate);
var formattedDate = `${match[3]}/${match[2]}/${match[1]}`
alert(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

**step 1** 
 create new ISO string and extract Date in yyyymmdd

```
var data = new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

**step2**
split from '-'

```
var date = data.split('-');
```

**step 3**
arrange the way you want

```
var newDate = date[2] +'-'+ date[1] +'-'+ date[0]
```

same as for HH:mm

```
new Date().toISOString().substring(11, 16);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can user `date-fns` js library in which you just need to do this.

```
import {format} from 'date-fns';
const date = format(new Date(), 'DD/MM/YYYY');
const time = format(new Date(), 'HH:mm');

console.log(date) => 30/11/2017
console.log(time) => 11:17
```

Comment: Your answer shouldn't rely on a library that isn't tagged or mentioned in the OP. Is there really a "fomrat" method? ;-)